# Rundeck upgrade comparability check

Tags: rundeck

Can we upgrade rundeck version 3.4 in RHEl 6.10.
Currently am using RHEl 6.10 and want to upgrade to v 3.4 from V3.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the 3.4-specific documentation and steps [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-rundeck-3.4.html#upgrading-to-rundeck-3-4). Also, you can jump to the latest version.